# Android digital signature using keystore certificate

Tags: android, ssl, cryptography, digital-signature, keystore

**Aim**

I have developed a JAVA application for Desktops for digitally sign PDF and XML files using x509 certificates stored in a PC by accessing keystore (Windows-MY). I am trying to develop same functionality in Android devices (Phone/Tablet), by accessing android keystore.

**Problem**

The X509 certificates can either be stored in a USB token or installed directly from SD Card in Settings > User Credentials. I think for USB token, manufacturer should support android os otherwise it will not get displayed in keystore. But what about the certificate I installed in user credentials. I am not sure which keystore to use in both cases.

I have tried all following keystores, but no luck.

```
 KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
 KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore"); // returns only trusted ca certificates not the certificates in User Credentials
 KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
 KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User credentials installed on device are available through Android KeyChain, not Android KeyStore

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html

> The KeyChain class provides access to private keys and their corresponding certificate chains in credential storage.

The usage is slightly different than Windows-MY because you need to ask the user to request an alias. Use `choosePrivateKeyAlias` ​​to prompt user for the signing certificate and `getPrivateKey` to recover the key